# ld OS X: unknown option -z

Tags: macos, gcc, linker, ld

I'm trying to compile a particular package for multi simulation called MUSIC (https://github.com/INCF/MUSIC). I didn't have any problems to compile it on ubuntu but when I try to compile it on os x I get this error:

```
ld: unknown option: -z
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libmusic.la] Error 1
```

I tried almost everything: `cross-compiling` (the cross-compiler does not work), using ld installed with binutils... but I always get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but I will answer for the sake of completion.

This was solved with https://github.com/INCF/MUSIC/pull/24.

It turns out I got the same error when trying to compile [csstidy](https://github.com/csstidy-c/csstidy.git). In my case I had to remove the linker flags directly in the Makefile.